# UISlider's Value Changed target is NOT called

Tags: ios, xib, uislider, target-action

I have a UISlider in the XIB file with an IBAction outlet hooked up to its corresponding view controller. Everything looks fine (see image below). However, when I actually move the slider in the simulator - the Value Changed (sliderValueChanged in the image) target is NOT being called. I have verified that viewDidLoad is being called and that the view controller is hooked up to the XIB.

Help!

[image]

Comment: uff. i set up a quick demo project with a viewcontroller from xib and everything works as expected. would you like to share your project?

Comment: You know, I started with a scene that was in a storyboard - then I cut and pasted the view inside that scene into an XIB file. I think it's screwing up with XCode.

Comment: yeah, has to have something to do with that...

Comment: How do I get my code to you privately ?

Comment: hmm... maybe a private repository on github? or you can archive and send it via mail. andre.slotta@gmail.com.

Comment: i do not see the code from your screenshot in the viewcontroller file you sent me?! :)

Comment: I removed it - go ahead and try make the IBAction yourself - and then put a breakpoint while running it in the simulator - you will see it never gets there

Comment: ok... you got mail!

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. The view controller wasn't retained in my project - so there was nothing for the slider to call on. Really silly. No problem with the XIB file at all. I always thought that the view retains it's view controller - and that the view is retained so long as it's in the view hierarchy. Am I wrong? Special thanks to @AndreSlotta for helping me.

EDIT:
Apparently a view does NOT retain its view controller:
[Does a UIView retain its view controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10107696/does-a-uiview-retain-its-view-controller)